# ngx-datatable custom headertemplate with inputfield sort iconposition

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I try to create a datatable with ngx-datatable, in this table i need to filter by column. I created in the headerdefinition a inputfield with an filterfunction. This works fine. I also add the sorting with custom header.

my clumn definition:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="createTimestamp" [minWidth]="getWidth(6)" [maxWidth]="getWidth(6)">
<ng-template let-column="column" ngx-datatable-header-template let-sort="sortFn">
  <span (click)="sort()">Erster Auftritt</span>
  <div class="reportfilterbackground">
    <input type="text" class="form-control reportfilter" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" [(ngModel)]="dateFilter">
  </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
  {{row.createTimestamp | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'}}
</ng-template>
```

It works fine but the sorticon is on the false position:

[image]

I show the DOM and i see the sorticon is added after the inputfield:
[image]

I tried to move the icon to the correct position with css, but unfortunately this does not work because the column widths and column names are very different.

Have anyone a idea how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it with css with display flex and order like this:

```
.datatable-header-cell-template-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.datatable-header-cell-template-wrap .sort-btn {
    align-self: center;
}
.datatable-header-cell-template-wrap .reportfilterbackground {
    order: 10;
}
```

"order: 2" would be enought, but if checkbox is enabled it have to be 3. To make sure the filter field is last I use 10.